# Java apache poi reading Arabic letters

Tags: java, apache-poi

formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(5));
I am using java app to read from excel
And it read Arabic when I run 
But when I belt the project as .jar file it give me ? Instead of Arabic letters

Comment: If you are invoking a jar file from command line , then use this command `start java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar <filename>.jar`

Comment: I use NetBeans can you explains a little more I didn't get it